# Haven't found DNS Unlocker in the Task Manager. Where could it be?

Tags: dns, virus, malware, adware

This morning I found DNS Unlocker on my workstation, and since then I am trying to remove it. I guess, I visit some wrong website yesterday during the lunchtime. I really need help with this. There’s the same advices in all guides, which I found, such as here: 
http://pcfixhelp.net/ads/1649-how-to-remove-dns-unlocker.

But I just don’t see DNS Unlocker in Task Manager! I open the controller and there is no such program, but there are a lot of processes with unknown manufacturers. Do  I need to delete all of them to clean my PC from DNS Unlocker? I left comments in all topics that I viewed, but so far there was no answer. I hope, that the members of this community will help me to cope with this problem.

Comment: [Remove “Ads by DNS Unlocker” virus (Uninstall Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-dns-unlocker-removal/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

You should eliminate every suspicious entry from your Task Manager and then reset your affected web browsers. Finally, make sure you fix your DNS settings with the help of these steps: 
1. Open "Control Panel" on your computer and go to "Network and Internet" -> "Network and Sharing Center"-> "Change Adapter Settings". You should see your active Internet connection.
2. Right-click it, select "Properties" and find "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)". Check it and click on "Properties" again. When in Properties window, make sure that “Obtain an IP address automatically” and “Obtain DNS server address automatically!” are selected. As we have already warned you, DNS Unlocker malware can try to change these settings to prevent its removal!
3. Select "OK” to save changes.